# Ajax wont Post to php after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to post variables to php. The Php file writes those variables into a text file. And the python script reads the variables out of the text file to control two electric motors. This works for about 15 seconds, but after that I have to reload the webpage to have control again. The python script isn't the problem, because when I write the variables manually in the text file it works even when the webpage doesn't.
So the problem is that after a few seconds the javascript/ajax script won't post the variables to the php file, I guess.

```
    function startajax(){ 
    $.ajax({
    url:"/motor.php",
          });
    }

    var v= 0;
    var q=0;
    function keyCode(event) {

        var x = event.keyCode;

        if (x == 37) {
            var z = v-10;
            if (z < -100) {
                z= -100;
            }
            v = z;

            document.getElementsByName('speedrechtsoutput')[0].value = v;

            var d = $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "text.php",
                data: {searchq: v, search: q},
            });

        };

        if (x == 39) {
            var z = v+10;

            if (z > 100) {
                z = 100;
            }

            v = z;

            document.getElementsByName('speedrechtsoutput')[0].value = v;

            var g = $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "text.php",
                data: {searchq: v, search: q},
            });
        };

        if (x == 65) {
            var m = q-10;

            if (m < -100) {
                m = -100;
            }

            q= m;

            document.getElementsByName('inputbox')[0].value = "";
            document.getElementsByName('speedlinksoutput')[0].value = q;

            var f = $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "text.php",
                data: {search: q, searchq: v},

            });
        };

        <!--(...)-->
    }
```

And the html

```
Input: <input type="text" name="inputbox" size="50" onkeydown="keyCode(event)">
<br> <br> <rb>

Speed Links: <input type="textbox" name="speedlinksoutput" value="0"></input>
Speed Rechts: <input type="textbox" name="speedrechtsoutput" value="0"></input>
```

The text.php file

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['searchq']) && $_POST['searchq'] != "" && isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != "")
{

    $name = $_POST['searchq'];
    $name = "$name\n";
    $handle = fopen ("datei.txt", "w");
    fwrite ($handle, $name);
    $test = $_POST['search'];
    $test="$test\n";
    fwrite($handle, $test);
    fclose ($handle);

    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably need to throttle the calls so you are not hammering your server witth the calls.

Comment: As i know `$.ajax` call URL once NOT repeatedly. and also I think you need a `success` function if you care about server response.

Comment: What is the browser debug console telling you?

Comment: @jeff the debug console isn't telling me any errors or warnings.